# replace string at specific location within a text file, using php

Tags: php, string

I have something like this:

```
//line1   1321 precalculus 30 0
//line2   1244 accounting 30 0
```

In a common text file.

How would I change the number `30` on line1 to `29`, `0` to `1` etc.

Comment: Well what have you tried? `explode()` comes to mind

Comment: `preg_replace()` could come in handy, if the number of words per line is constant.

Comment: ok, i like where you going. numbe rof string/line will always be consatnt. what's next?

Comment: as for explode()...well i can't think of how that would come in handy when Writing on files.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest of cases, like the one you described, assuming you know what line you want to change and what you want it to change to, this works:

```
// Get text file contents as array of lines
$txt = file('text.txt'); 

// Make the change to line 1
$txt[0] = "1321 precalculus 29 1"; 

// Put the lines back together, and write back into txt file
file_put_contents('text.txt', implode("\n", $txt));
```

This may not be effective depending on what you are really trying to do. Essentially it just splits the text file by line, then overwrites line 1 with the new data, then rewrites the whole thing back to the text file. Again, depending on how big your file is and what you are really trying to accomplish, this may not be the best solution. But it does do what you described and might be a good place to start.

**Update** As pointed out in Jorg's comment, exploding the file contents in two steps is not necessary, as `file()` will accomplish the same task in one step.

Comment: You could use `file` to get it into an array without the explode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. You could still use explode to do calculations on the numbers.

Comment: would doing the above wipe out $txt[1] (line2)?

Comment: No, I've tested it and it works. You are only overwriting `$txt[0]` in the array created, leaving `$txt[1]` intact. Then you are simply rewriting both lines back into the text file, with only the first changed (2nd step in above code).